# adding cpp files to a cscope database

Tags: c++, cscope

Do I really have to combine a recursive grep or find in conjunction with scope to add .cpp files to a cscope database ?

Is there a simple pattern matching argument that will work seamlessly with the existing -R argument to cscope ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have `cscope: version 15.7a` and it process my `.cpp`, `.cc` files as a source files in subdirectories with `cscope -R`. `mlcscope` in cygwin works the same way.

So we have obsolete information at [Using Cscope on large projects](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html):

> by default Cscope only parses files with the .c, .h, .y, or .l extensions

In the newest sources of cscope I've found function `static BOOL
issrcfile(char *path)` which has **hardcoded** set of extensions: `c h l y C G H L bp qc qh sd cc hh tcc cpp cxx hpp hxx` recognised as source code files.

Also manpage says nothing about regex or patterns for work with `-R`.